# Create a scroll with higher than default DC

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, magic-items, crafting

When a scroll is crafted the DC for the effect is always set to the lowest possibly ability score.

$$
\begin{array}{l|l|l}
\text{Spell Level} & \text{Lowest Ability Score} & \text{Final DC} \\
\hline
0 & 10 (+0) & 10 \\
1 & 11 (+0) & 11 \\
2 & 12 (+1) & 13 \\
3 & 13 (+1) & 14 \\
4 & 14 (+2) & 16 \\
5 & 15 (+2) & 17 \\
6 & 16 (+3) & 19 \\
7 & 17 (+3) & 20 \\
8 & 18 (+4) & 22 \\
9 & 19 (+4) & 23  \\
\end{array}
$$

Yes its possible to create a 1st level spell as a 4th level spell to bypass less globe of invulnerability using heighten spell. What I am asking is it possible to create a 1st level scroll but increase the DC by changing the ability score? I know the rules do not have this or else the formula would state it. Is there a class ability to create a scroll (not use it as I know there are one or two which allows you to use your ability scroll or caster level) with this higher DC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Nothing seems to do what you want.

The DC being based on the minimum Ability Score is baked into [Magic Items](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Saving-Throws-Against-Magic-Item-Powers).

> Magic items produce spells or spell-like effects. **For a saving throw against a spell or spell-like effect from a magic item, the DC is 10 + the level of the spell or effect + *the ability modifier of the minimum ability score* needed to cast that level of spell.**
>
> Staves are an exception to the rule. Treat the saving throw as if the wielder cast the spell, including caster level and all modifiers to save DCs.
>
> Most item descriptions give saving throw DCs for various effects, particularly when the effect has no exact spell equivalent (making its level otherwise difficult to determine quickly).

It's worth noting that Scribing a Heightened *spell* would slightly increase the DC due to the higher level spell.

---

### These are the closest abilities I can find.

There are a [significant number of classes and archetypes](https://cse.google.com/cse?cx=006680642033474972217%3A6zo0hx_wle8&q=scroll#gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=scroll&gsc.ref=more%3Aclasses&gsc.sort=) that interact with scrolls. Unfortunately, they only seem to care about *using* scrolls, not Scribing them.

- [Scrollmaster](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/archetypes/paizo-wizard-archetypes/scrollmaster/) Wizards can *cast* spells from scrolls using their Intelligence
- [Scroll Mastery](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus/magus-arcana/paizo-magus-arcana/scroll-mastery-su/) allows Magi to *cast* spells from scrolls using their Intelligence at the cost of 1 Arcane Pool point
- The [Cyphermage](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/c-d/cyphermage/) Prestige Class can select the ability to use their spellcasting Score when *casting* from a scroll, up to (level/3) times per day
- The Petersen Games' [Ritualist](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/archetypes/petersen-games-wizard-archetypes/ritualist-wizard-archetype/) Wizard can use their spellcasting Score when *casting* from a scroll by doubling the casting time
- The [Arcane Savant](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/a-b/arcane-savant/) Prestige Class uses their own CL instead of items', including scrolls, starting at 3rd level
- The Louis Porter Jr Design's [Arcanamechanist](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/3rd-party-classes/louis-porter-jr-design/machinesmith/archetypes/louis-porter-jr-design-machinesmith-archetypes/arcanamechanist/) Machinesmith can use their own class level instead of a wand or scrolls' CL, up to Int +3 times per day, starting at 2nd level

---

And, for completeness, Scrolls *are* a "Spell Completion" Magic Item as referenced in the Magic Items section.

> **Spell Completion:** This is the activation method for scrolls. A scroll is a spell that is mostly finished. The preparation is done for the caster, so no preparation time is needed beforehand as with normal spellcasting. All that’s left to do is perform the finishing parts of the spellcasting (the final gestures, words, and so on). To use a spell completion item safely, a character must be of high enough level in the right class to cast the spell already. If he can’t already cast the spell, there’s a chance he’ll make a mistake. Activating a spell completion item is a standard action (or the spell’s casting time, whichever is longer) and provokes attacks of opportunity exactly as casting a spell does.

Comment: Arcane savant is cool and didnt know that one. Im actually surprised that there isnt a rule somewhere (except for maybe height-ed scrolls) that allows the DC to increase for a scroll. However I can also see scrolls of higher DC save or suck as being game breaking so maybe this was intentional.

Comment: It would turn anyone with UMD and money into a high level caster potentially. Have a Wizard with 30 Int, Scribe Scroll and 10 days? Guess whose party all has DC 29 Meteor Swarms?! (or whatever. I know there are better spells)